# Error trying to upgrade git

Tags: git, upgrade

I have git 1.8.2 on my Mac OSX 10.7.5 and I'd like to upgrade to the latest version.  I entered these commands in Terminal:

```
git clone git://github.com/gitster/git.git 
cd git 
sudo make prefix=/usr install install-doc install-html install-info
```

When I ran the sude make... command, Terminal told me it couldn't find the make command, so I went to Xcode > Preferences > Downloads and installed the command line tools.  Then Terminal was able to find the make command, but I got this error when I re-tried the last it:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [git-credential-store] Error 1
```

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this error so I can upgrade git.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of downloading and compiling git yourself, you may use [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) or [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh/) to do that. Even if you don't want to use one of them, you may take a look on the formula used to install git to see how it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install git on OS X is to use the installer at http://git-scm.com.

Also, when building from source, it's best not to install anything into `/usr`, in order to not change the system's existing software. It's best to install to `/usr/local`, and prioritise `/usr/local/bin` in your $PATH.

As for the build failure, it can't really be diagnosed from just that message. There are quite a few things that could cause it.